# I want to create a id whenever i click on submit button and there is no use of backend in angular

Tags: php, angular, angular-material, ionic4

I want to create a id whenever i click on submit button and there is no use of back end in angular. My form:

```
<form>    
<ion-grid>      
 <ion-button  size="large" type="submit"(click)="login()" expand="block">Register</ion-button>
</ion-grid>         
 </form>
```

page.ts

```
login() {     

 this.divs.push(this.divs.length);  
console.log(this.divs.length)     
 console.log(this.divs)    

this.storage.set('id',this.divs.length).then((response) => {

 this.storage.set('USER_INFO', this.model).then((response) => {

 this.authState.next(true);
  console.log(response);      

 });    
  console.log(response);

});

}
```

Comment: Problem statement is not clear, can you add more information.

Comment: My data is stored in offline storage and in that storage there is no id. But i want a id of every user in increment format and generate a message that your registration id is this.

Answer (score 0):

Normally it is the database's job to create the ID. But since you don't have a backend, you can have a look at the `uuid` library. I believe your Angular project is already referencing it so no further installation from npm is needed. You just need to import it into your TS files.

Answer (score 0):

if you want unique id without any library, you can just set the id as follows

```
id = Date.now(); // it will return current dateTime in number like 1572674004071
```

this will solve your purpose.